# Controlling registration of new user in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, user-registration

I would like to have more control on the way new users can register on my WP website. 
They should be able to register by themselves if they have a valid email address on a particular domain (e.g. rolland@thisdomain.au). If they register with an email address on a different domain (e.g. rolland@otherdomain.au), the administrator of the site should decide whether to allow the registration or reject it.

Ideally I'd like to NOT use plugins and implement this directly in a custom theme (or my own custom plugin).

Any suggestions ?

Comment: do you want to use on frontside for new user registration? @Guitar

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. I'm fine with the frontend for now, I can keep WP's login/registration form as it is. It's what happens after that's a problem for me.